# Bizzare behavior of NotifyDataSetChanged() Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, notifydatasetchanged, android-7.1-nougat

I am working on an application that asks the user to provide photos for items.

My main object is following

```
public class PickedObject
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    int Name{ get; set; }
    bool HasPhotos { get; set; }
}
```

And I have another table for Photos since one item can have multiple photos.

What's happening is that in my adapter, I have created a recycler view so that if an Item has images, there should be an ImageButton visible in front of it.

Here is my row template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="8">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblItemName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/rowcamera"
            android:id="@+id/btnCamera" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/rowpicture"
            android:id="@+id/btnPicture" />     
</LinearLayout>
```

In my adapter I am using the following in `GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`

```
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ItemViewHolder holder = null;
        PickedObject item = _items[position];
        View view = convertView;

        try
        { 
            if (view != null)
                holder = (ItemViewHolder)view.Tag; //Holder

            if(holder == null)
            {
                holder = new ItemViewHolder();
                view = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ItemRow, null);
                holder.ItemName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblItemName);

                holder.CameraButton = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnCamera);
                holder.CameraButton.Tag = item.ID;   
                holder.PictureButton = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnPicture);
                holder.PictureButton.Tag = item.ID;                    

                CameraClickListener cameraListener = new CameraClickListener(_context, this); 
                cameraListener.CameraClickEvent += CameraClickedEvent;
                holder.CameraButton.SetOnClickListener(cameraListener);
                ImageClickListener imageClickListener = new ImageClickListener(_context);
                imageClickListener.ImageClickEvent += ImageClickedEvent;
                holder.PictureButton.SetOnClickListener(imageClickListener);                                        
                view.Tag = holder;
            }

            holder.ItemName.Text = item.Name;               
            holder.CameraButton.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

            if (item.HasPhotos)
            {
                holder.PictureButton.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
            else
            {
                holder.PictureButton.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Item adapter", ex.Message);
        }
        return view;
    }
```

Now in my MainActivity I have called two activities (for result), One is the camera activity that starts the camera and saves the photo.
The other activity is a gallery type activity that is created within the project.

The activity on result is called as follows:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    int itemId = CameraApp.ID; // Camera App is a static object to hold data
    if (requestCode == General.CAMERA_ACTIVITY) // Camera activity code 110
    {
        CompleteCameraActivity(resultCode, data); // Save picture into gallery and update db
    }
    if(requestCode == General.GALLERY_ACTIVITY) // Gallery activity code 113
    {
        CompleteGalleryActivity(resultCode, data);
    }

    SectionFragment frag = (SectionFragment)sectionsAdapter.GetItem(viewPager.CurrentItem);
    int sectionId = frag.Section.ID;        
    frag.Adapter.SetPicture(questionId, dataAccess.HasPictures(itemId));        
}
```

The `SetPicture` method in the adapter is as follows:

```
public void SetPicture(int id, bool hasPics)
{
    Item itm = _items.SingleOrDefault(a => a.ID == id);
    if (itm != null)
        _items.SingleOrDefault(a => a.ID == id).HasPhotos = hasPics;

    this.NotifyDataSetChanged();        
}
```

The application works fine when it comes from Camera activity. It updates the record and also the image button is visible as well.
The trouble comes when the MainActivity gains control after GalleryActivity. When I delete all the images in the gallery the `SetPicture` method is executed which makes the `HasPhotos` property to false. But the `NotifyDataSetChanged` part of the adapter doesn't work (when I test it in debugger the `GetView` method is not fired for the adapter).

So what happens is that my ListView remains in a state where even if the item has no photos the ImageButton (for pictures) is still available.
Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I noticed that if I scroll the list once and return back to the item, the ImageButton is invisible, that means that it is working but why doesn't it work in `StartActivityForResult`?

Comment: I had a similar issue with my settings, that some views simply failed to follow up with the change until I did the flip-flopping you say you do before the change appeared. Turns out I had some event handlers in the code-behind of my XAML that didn't pass through to my ViewModel.. I "fixed" it by putting calling the bindingcontext at the beginning and end of each of these changers; with viewModel.IsBusy = true; at the top and viewModel.isBusy = false; in the end. Which solved it. It feels like a hack, but it worked instantly.

Comment: How can I put this in Xamarin.Android? @JanAndersen I think your problem may have been in xamarin forms.

Comment: Yes, I am using MVVM. It's a little hard to tell where you go wrong when you only give partial code. It's not clear how GetView fits into the picture. I guess it's possible that you might have to make the Notify from OnActivityResult itself or perhaps pop the listview from the stack since it's loaded with old news..

Comment: Well, the `GetView` is fired everytime the datasetchange is notified. I can see it being fired (with a breakpoint) when the app returns from the `CompleteCameraActivity`, but the same doesn't happen when the app comes back from `CompleteGalleryActivity`. Both of them are part of the `OnActivityResult` if condition.

Comment: So the problem is connected to the code you didn't include here? That makes it a little hard to help.. I guess ;)